# A question about vcpkg and pcl/visualization

Tags: c++, pcl

first, I used :

```
./vcpkg install pcl
```

to install pcl. However, I don't notice that this command could not install vtk and use pcl/visualization. I succeed in installing and using pcl(except visualiztion).
So, I try follow :

```
./vcpkg install pcl[vtk,qt] --rescure
```

Actually, when I wanted to use I could still not `#include<pcl/visualiztion/..>`

Comment: What build system do you use, and how do you configure it to use vcpkg packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to run it the following way to fix this issue:

```
vcpkg install pcl[vtk]:x64-windows --featurepackages --recurse
```

Not sure whether `x64-windows` specifier is important, but keep in mind that VCPKG installs x86 libraries by default. Also please not that the option you have used is misspelled: it is `--recurse`, not `--rescure`.

If you are using CMake, remember to use the toolchain file:

```
cmake -B [build directory] -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=[path to vcpkg]/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
```

Answer (score 0):

This command really works, which was mentioned by https://stackoverflow.com/a/71861246/23477900:

```bash
vcpkg install pcl[vtk]:x64-windows --featurepackages --recurse
```

And then I find it necessary to manually set the **include directory** in the property option of `Visual Studio` project.

Include the path where the `vtk` is installed, like:

```
C:\src\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\vtk-9.2
```

Then I succeed, ending up with termination of this painful debugging.